# JQuery validation plugin pattern based validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with 5 input fields and i have the validation as below. I am using jquery validation plugin.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

### JQuery code:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    rules: {
     cname1: { required : true, minlength: 2 },
     cname2: { required : true, minlength: 2 },
     cname3: { required : true, minlength: 2 },
     cname4: { required : true, minlength: 2 },
     cname5: { required : true, minlength: 2 }
    }
});
```

The validation works fine without any issues. My requirement is, as you can see all the input names starts fiwth `cname`. Here instead of defining rules for all fields which are starting with same name `cname`, can i define rules based on pattern? similar to `$('[name^="cname"]')`  ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#commentForm").validate();
$('#commentForm [name^="cname"]').each(function() {

 $(this).rules('add', { required : true, minlength: 2 });

});
```

Also check [jQuery.validator.addClassRules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules#rules) for adding your own class based rules (like .min-2 or smth)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$( "[name^='cname']" ).rules( "add", {
  required: true,
  minlength: 2
});
```

More info: http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules. And remember to:

> equires that the parent form is validated, that is, $( “form” ).validate() is called first

Comment: It needs $.each afaik